# Replace image with text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html code look like this

```
<a class="wsl_connect_with_provider" title="Connect with Facebook" data-provider="Facebook">
<img src="/assets/img/facebook.png">
</a>
<a class="wsl_connect_with_provider" title="Connect with Twitter" data-provider="Twitter">
<img src="/assets/img/twitter.png">
</a>
```

I would like to replace the `img` with `title` using `jquery` like this.

```
<a class="wsl_connect_with_provider" title="Connect with Facebook" data-provider="Facebook">
    Connect with Facebook
    </a>
    <a class="wsl_connect_with_provider" title="Connect with Twitter" data-provider="Twitter">
    Connect with Twitter
    </a>
```

Can someone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Please try first, then come back with your code and people may help you out. Good luck!

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/an7vj/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('a.wsl_connect_with_provider').each(function(){
  $(this).text($(this).prop('title'));
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/an7vj/)**

Comment: This is correct and straight-forward, but it doesn't replace img with text?

Comment: @Omar, did you se the demo? img is child of `a`, so `.text()` replaces it.

Comment: I just did, then .text() considers img a text? Never came through this before, it's good to know :)

Comment: @Omar, `$(this)` inside each() is `a` element and .text() replaces the content of `$(this)` with `$(this).prop('title')`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each($('img'), function(){
  $(this).replaceWith('<span>'+$(this).attr('title')+'</span>');
});
```

Comment: Its not working correctly. Thanks for the try though.

Comment: `$.each($('img'), function(){
  $(this).replaceWith('<span>'+$(this).closest('a').attr('title')+'</span>');
});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.wsl_connect_with_provider img').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith(
        $(this.parentNode).attr('title')
    );
});
```